# zero always returns to null in php isset

Tags: php, codeigniter, isset

am new in php..i am trying to filter my datas from db by using dropdownlist..my code in view form is like

```
   <?php 
    if(isset($value))
    {
       if($value==1)
      {
      echo"<option value='1' selected>option1</option>
           <option value='0' >option2</option>";    
      } 

      if($value==0)
      {
      echo"<option value='1' >option1</option>
           <option value='0' selected >option2</option>";   
      }    
    }           
    else    
    {
      echo"<option value='1'>option1</option>
           <option value='0'>option2</option>"; 
           $value="";
    }              

  ?>
```

but if am selecting option1 its working correctly..but when am clicking option2 its filtering the correct datas but its selecting the status only..selected value is status ,ie same as null value...

Comment: If `$status` is `0`, are you getting the options? Try `if ($status === '0')`.

Comment: please elaborate on "clicking inactive its filtering the correct datas but its selecting the status only..selected value is status ,ie same as null value... "

Comment: archer.. when am clicking inactive the datas displaying correctly.. but in the dropdownlist the selected value will be status..that is the displaying datas will be corresponding to inactive and in the dropdown list it will be 'Status'..

Comment: putvande ..yes..if $status is 0,in the table datas its getting correct value only..but the problem is in the dropdown list..if the value is '' or 0 ,always dropdown list will show only status..i need to get 
'Active ' for '1'
'Inactive' for '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try replacing your code with this

```
<select name="status" id="status">
<option value=""><< Select Option >></option>
<option value="1" <?=($status=="1")?"selected":""?>>Active</option>
<option value="0" <?=($status=="0")?"selected":""?>>Inactive</option>           
</select>
```

Its small and ternary operator is fast then if else conditions.

Comment: It should work if you are getting the value in the variable $status and if then also the problem resist try typecasting the $status into integer and in the ternary operator place 1 and zero 0 without quotes and replace == with ===

Comment: here the problem is zero taking as null value why?

Comment: Do one thing set the default value of the $status variable to 0 so it will not take the null and when you got 1 from request or the database change the $status value to 1 it will show active and by default it will show inactive.

IF you want to make the default option << Select Option >>  then declare $status='';  and then you can assign value 1 or 0 accordingly

Comment: You can all the data from the database and then at all the dropdoowns you can put conditions to show the selected value, in your case you were getting null in place of 0 so its better to assign some value so it will not take null by default

Comment: can you please post the code for the view page it will be helpful to answer after that

Comment: You can have my email id from my profile please up-vote the answer also thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before adressing your filtering problem that may need some more explanation
I'll suggest to refactor your code to avoid unnecessary conditions and code duplication

This is one way to do it :

```
<?php $values   = array('Inactive', 'Active') ?>
<?php $selected = (!empty($status)) ? 'selected' : ''  ?>

<?php foreach($values as $value => $label): ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $value ?>' <?php echo $selected ?> ><?php echo $label ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```